# Efficiently mutate characters in a binary string based on given probability

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to efficiently mutate values in a binary string based on a random number probability. Below is a block of code I generated, and it works, but I believe it could be done better to reduce the time and memory usage when carrying into manipulation of thousands of binary strings.

```
b = '111111'
c = [random.random() for x in range(len(b))]

for x in range(len(b)):
    z = list(b)
    if c[x] <= 0.3:
        print(x, True)
        z[x] = '0'
        b = ''.join(z)
    else:
        print(x, False)
```

Using this code will generate a result similar to `b = '011010'` based on the random numbers generated. Although this is the outcome I want, I believe there is a more efficient way of constructing this code so I don't have to re-list and re-join `b` during each iteration of the for-loop. Any input on making this more efficient would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: work directly with integers

Comment: Jean-Francois Fabre: the issue with working directly with integers in the model I'm building is that the converter from integer to binary produces strings, and then the reverse requires strings. On top of that, there is a lot of binary concatenation that doesn't work well with integers.

Comment: then parse string => int, generate & convert back to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a list comprehension to be consumed by the `join` method.

```
b = ''.join(["1" if random.random() > 0.3 else "0" for _ in b])
```

Comment: Might as well use a list-comprehension here, it will be faster

Comment: chepner: The idea is to mutate a `0` to a `1` or a `1` to a `0` if the random number is below a certain value. Would list comprehension still work in this case?

Comment: You can't mutate a string; all you can do is create a new string based on the elements of the original.

Answer (score 2):

a full mathematical solution uses only bits (and `log2` to compute the number of "digits" of `b` or better, as suggested in comments, `bit_length`). This doesn't involve strings (except for parsing at start & printing in the end)

```
import random,math

b = 0b11111   # or int(b,2) to parse from string
new_b = 0
for x in range(b.bit_length()):
    # or shifted random bit
    new_b |= bool(random.random() > 0.3) <<x
```

example output:

```
>>> bin(new_b)
'0b11101'
```

Comment: You can use `b.bit_length()` instead of log2.

Comment: Today I learned about `bit_length()` wow... Also this is more readable than "compact, so obviously better" accepted answer. +1

Comment: thanks. It's more a matter of performance for not using strings at all.

Comment: I understand that much, strings in all languages aren't something I like working with, and in Python they are objects so the only thing that saves the other answer from being just as slow is probably (I don't know much about caching itself, Python definitely caches objects though) string value buffer and string object caching that Python Interpreter employs. Also I just simply don't like oneliners because they look like bad codegolf attempt and barely explain anything, but that's okay, at least the asker gets impressed, and copy pasting just works...

Comment: I don't agree with list comprehensions being bad. It's generally okay, and in that case short enough to be understandable. But you cannot list-comprehened a bit mask accumulation. That's one of the reasons I didn't create one.